# Return in a 'finally' statement

Tags: java, file, stream

I'm trying to read ObjectOutputStream from a file and convert it to an arraylist.
This whole thing is happening inside a method which should read the file and return the array list:

```
public static List<Building> readFromDatabase(){
    String fileName="database.txt";
    FileInputStream fileIStream=null;
    ObjectInputStream in=null;
    List<Building> buildingsArr=null;
    try
     {
        fileIStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIStream);
        buildingsArr=(ArrayList<Building>)in.readObject();
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
     {
        Console.printPrompt("ArrayList<Building> class not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    finally{
        Console.printPrompt("Closing file...");
        close(in);
        close(fileIStream);
        return buildingsArr;
    }
}
```

Java tells me that this is dangerous.
What are the alternatives?
I can't put the return in the "try" block because it won't do it / it won't close files in the "finally" block.
I need to both make sure files will be closed, and return the array list I created as well.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just put the `return` statement after the `finally` block?

Comment: `close(fileIStream);` can (in fact should) be left out, as `in.close()` will close it.

Comment: As a side note, it is dangerous because the possibility of something like that: `try { return true; } finally { return false; }`

Comment: and close(fileOStream) is ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I can't put the return in the "try" block because it won't do it / it
>   won't close files in the "finally" block.

Wrong, finally block would still execute if you put return in try block. Thus you can return in your try block.

```
try
     {
        //your code
        return buildingsArr;
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
     {
        Console.printPrompt("ArrayList<Building> class not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    finally{
        Console.printPrompt("Closing file...");
        close(in);
        close(fileIStream);
    }
```

Comment: i need both return and finally to happen. will return still happen, before the finally clause? if yes , problem solved

Comment: They both will happen. Finally will be executed before the return statement.

Comment: This doesn't even compile, if you don't throw an `Exception` out or return something after the `finally`! **As is this is NOT a correct answer!**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting to use Java 7, and the try with resources clause. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Ex:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You must either throw an Exception or return a value:

All you need to prove this is comment out the `return "File Not Found"` after the `finally` block and see that it won't compile.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ReturnFinallyExample
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        returnFinally();
    }

    private static String returnFinally()
    {
        try
        {
            final File f = new File("that_does_not_exist!");
            final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            return "File Found!";
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("finally!");
        }
        return "File Not Found!";
    }
}
```

You must have the `return` after the `finally` or you have to either:

declare the method to `throws FileNotFoundExceptoin` and re-throw the `FileNotException` out.

or

wrap the `FileNotFoundException` with `throw new RuntimeException(e)`